# Echo back a newly generated (auto increment) user id immediately after form submission?

Tags: php, html, forms, mysqli, echo

After my users submit some basic info in a form, how do I get the newly created userID to be echoed back to a hidden field on the header (redirect) page?

The first form contains basis Name, Phone, Email inputs. When user submits form (to database), the AI 'userID' column generates their unique 'userID'.

I need that unique ID to echo back to a hidden field on the header (redirect) page where the user will then upload their profile photo.

New User Form:

```
<h1>New User Form</h1>

<form action="newUser_formHandler.php" method="POST" >

<input name="userName" placeholder="Enter Name"><br><br>

<input name="userPhone" placeholder="Enter Phone"><br><br>

<input name="userEmail" placeholder="Enter Email"><br><br>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">

</form>
```

New User Form Handler:

```
<?php include './secure/dbKey.php';?>

<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

$userName = $_POST['userName'] ;
$userPhone = $_POST['userPhone'] ;
$userEmail = $_POST['userEmail'] ;

$newUser = "insert into Users (userName, userPhone, userEmail)

values('$userName', '$userPhone', '$userEmail')";

$run = mysqli_query($conn,$newUser) or die(mysqli_error()) ;


//Page Re-direct after form submission

header('location: /profilePhoto_UploadPage.php');

}

?>
```

Profile Photo Upload Page:

```
<?php include './secure/dbKey.php';?>

<html>

<head>

    <title>Profile Photo Upload Page</title>

</head>

<body>

    <h1>Congratulations!</h1>

    <h2>Your profile was succesfully created!</h2>

    <a>Please upload a photo to complete your profile:</a><br><br>

<form action="photoUpload_Handler.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

  <input type="hidden" name="userID" id="userID" value="<?php echo $userID; ?>">

  <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload"><br><br>

  <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">

</form>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: See https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php for `how do I get the newly created userID`. If the question is more specific to DOM outputting please clarify. This code is open to SQL injections. Use parameterized queries.

Comment: `mysqli_error()` will not work as the `mysqli_*` version of this requires a DB connection. You also should not throw errors to the console. Log them and view your logs.

Comment: @Phil Thanks for answering. The header adjustments seems easy to understand. But  before I insert this, I just want to understand correctly, would I retrieve the value as such;  value="<?php echo $conn->insert_id; ?>"    ??

Comment: You would be better using SESSIONs. With this approach anyone can manipulate DOM and assume another's role. Also, how does a user reupload anything, or it is a 1 time process?

Comment: you need to comment on the answer for the answer to receive notices.

Comment: Related: [Send Ajax post request and retrieve the inserted id](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40798479/2943403) and [How to get last inserted id using AJAX?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34041357/2943403) and [How to access last inserted userid in ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43339039/2943403) and [How can I get " last inserted id to database " in Jquery Success Method?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25988753/2943403) and [Ajax, retrieving ID of insert from within function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51499363/2943403)

Comment: [jQuery/AJAX retrieving ID of newly inserted record and using this in HTML before page refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16167890/2943403) and [Using returned ajax ID in other calls to database](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51503146/2943403) and [Get Data in Ajax Response After Successful Insert Query in Codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54234332/2943403) and [CodeIgniter, Ajax... How to use insert_id()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51492828/2943403) and [Jquery $ajax POST data and get a response mysqli_insert_id](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29143517/2943403)

Comment: Very closely related: [how to redirect to different page through ajax in php](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45233945/2943403) and [jQuery AJAX Onchange Redirect Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62047891/2943403) and [Ajax Redirect on new page and after display success message](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38410655/2943403)

Comment: And [How to redirect URL by id in PHP while inserting data into database](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59217221/2943403)

Comment: All duplicates provided are much worse than answer provided below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Retrieve the value using [`$conn->insert_id`](https://www.php.net/manual/mysqli.insert-id.php) and either pass it in the query string or set it into the session.

Also, whatever tutorial or guide you're following is seriously out-of-date or just plain bad. Use [prepared statements](https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli#prepare) and follow a [good tutorial](https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli_examples/insert)

```php
$stmt = $conn->prepare(
    "INSERT INTO `Users` (`userName`, `userPhone`, `userEmail`) VALUES (?, ?, ?)"
);
$stmt->bind_param(
    "sss",
    $_POST["userName"],
    $_POST["userPhone"],
    $_POST["userEmail"]
);
$stmt->execute();

header(
    "Location: /profilePhoto_UploadPage.php?" .
        http_build_query(["userID" => $conn->insert_id])
);
exit();
```

On the secondary page you'd use the query parameter

```php-template
<input
  type="hidden"
  name="userID"
  id="userID"
  value="<?= htmlspecialchars($_GET['userID']) ?>"
/>
```

---

Using a session is just as easy

```php
session_start();

// same mysqli code as above

$_SESSION['userID'] = $conn->insert_id;
header('Location: /profilePhoto_UploadPage.php');
exit;
```

On the secondary page you wouldn't really need it as whatever page you're posting to would also be able to read the session

```php
// photoUpload_Handler.php
session_start();
$userID = $_SESSION['userID'];
```